# Tableview populating from database in separate queue

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm implementing a simple tableview, which gets data from a SQLite database. I have this code:

```
-(void)fetchDataFromDb
{

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self cleanAllArrays];

    __block NSMutableArray* newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("workingQueuee", NULL);
    dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                   ^{
                       newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbAcess getAllClipBoards]];

                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          self.allClipboards = newAllClipboards;
                                          [self sortClipboardsSentOrDelivered];
                                          [self.tableVIew reloadData];
                                          [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                      });
                   });
}
```

The problem is that the cell is empty when added. The interesting thing is that when I do it all on the main thread, everything is just fine:

```
-(void)fetchDataFromDb
{

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("workingQueuee", NULL);
    dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                   ^{
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          [self cleanAllArrays];
                                          self.allClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbAcess getAllClipBoards]];
                                          [self sortClipboardsSentOrDelivered];
                                          [self.tableVIew reloadData];
                                          [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                                      });

                   });
}
```

I just don't understand this.

Comment: what does getAllClipBoards method have? Are you doing any UI related stuff in that method?

Comment: It creates NSArray of objects ClipboardData, and this object has UILabel inside, which is created, this UILabel is added as subview to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: is ClipboardData is a subclass of UIView?

Comment: This is class definition `
@interface PCClipboardData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSString* clipboardText;
@property (nonatomic) NSString* clipboardImage;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate* time;
@property BOOL isText;
@property BOOL sent;
@property (nonatomic) UIView* view;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber* DbId;

-(id)initWithText:(NSString*)text sent:(BOOL)mSent andTime:(NSDate*)mTime;
-(id)initWithImageFileUrl:(NSString*)mImageUrl Sent:(BOOL)mSent Time:(NSDate*)mTime;
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)mImage Sent:(BOOL)mSent Time:(NSDate*)mTime;
@end
` SORRY FOR THAT FORMAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel issue is because you are trying to access objects of `ClipboardData` in `getAllClipBoards`, using separate thread other than main thread. `ClipboardData` has UI components in it. So, you are accessing them in a non-main thread, which is causing issue.

If you try to call `getAllClipBoards` in a main thread then you wont see any issue.

Comment: Yes you are right, problem is that getAllClipBoards is fetching data from database, that was the reason why I wanted to put it into separate thread, so I changed code to load data in separate thread, but create UI components in main queue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
-(void)fetchDataFromDb
{

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self cleanAllArrays];

    __block NSMutableArray* newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("workingQueuee", NULL);
    dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                   ^{
                       newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbAcess getAllClipBoards]];
                       typeof(newAllClipboards) __weak weakObj = newAllClipboards;
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          self.allClipboards = weakObj;
                                          [self sortClipboardsSentOrDelivered];
                                          [self.tableVIew reloadData];
                                          [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                      });
                   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this doesn't help, it resolves into blank tableview.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)fetchDataFromDb
{

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self cleanAllArrays];

    __block NSMutableArray* newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dispatch_queue_t workingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("workingQueuee", NULL);
    dispatch_async(workingQueue,
                   ^{
                       newAllClipboards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:           [self.dbAcess getAllClipBoards]];
                        self.allClipboards = newAllClipboards;
                        [self sortClipboardsSentOrDelivered];
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          [self.tableVIew reloadData];
                                          [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                      });
                   });
}
```

Try doing this way.